# Error with puppeteer with alpine Docker in chromium headless

Tags: puppeteer, chromium, alpine-linux, google-chrome-headless, firefox-headless

I'm trying to use pageres in my bash script for grabbing screenshot in heruko.
But running [pageres](https://github.com/sindresorhus/pageres) with `alpine:latest` throws error with puppeteer.

```
Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
[0318/133905.228580:FATAL:setuid_sandbox_host.cc(158)] The SUID sandbox helper binary was found, but is not configured correctly. Rather than run without sandboxing I'm aborting now. You need to make sure that /usr/lib/chromium/chrome-sandbox is owned by root and has mode 4755.
Received signal 6
  r8: 00007fff02e9e180  r9: 00007f65b4e1eb0c r10: 0000000000000008 r11: 0000000000000246
 r12: 00007fff02e9e820 r13: 00007fff02e9e95c r14: 00007fff02e9e5f0 r15: 0000000000000116
  di: 0000000000000002  si: 00007fff02e9e010  bp: 00007fff02e9e010  bx: 0000000000000000
  dx: 0000000000000000  ax: 0000000000000000  cx: 00007f65b96113f1  sp: 00007fff02e9e008
  ip: 00007f65b96113f1 efl: 0000000000000246 cgf: 0000000000000033 erf: 0000000000000000
 trp: 0000000000000000 msk: 0000000000000000 cr2: 0000000000000000
[end of stack trace]


TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md

    at onClose (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pageres-cli/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:193:20)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pageres-cli/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:184:79)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:532:35)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
```

I followed the troubleshooting docs at [puppeteer git](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-on-alpine) and added these lines to my dockerfile:

```
# Installs latest Chromium (92) package.
RUN apk add --no-cache \
      chromium \
      nss \
      freetype \
      harfbuzz \
      ca-certificates \
      ttf-freefont \
      nodejs \
      yarn

# Tell Puppeteer to skip installing Chrome. We'll be using the installed package.
ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=true \
    PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH=/usr/bin/chromium-browser

# Puppeteer v10.0.0 works with Chromium 92.
RUN yarn add puppeteer@10.0.0

# Add user so we don't need --no-sandbox.
RUN addgroup -S pptruser && adduser -S -G pptruser pptruser \
    && mkdir -p /home/pptruser/Downloads /app \
    && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /home/pptruser \
    && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /app
```

Also I tried firefox in headless mode for grabbing screenshot, that too throws error...

```
*** You are running in headless mode.
Crash Annotation GraphicsCriticalError: |[0][GFX1-]: glxtest: libpci missing (t=0.323898) [GFX1-]: glxtest: libpci missing
Crash Annotation GraphicsCriticalError: |[0][GFX1-]: glxtest: libpci missing (t=0.323898) |[1][GFX1-]: glxtest: libGL.so.1 missing (t=0.32393) [GFX1-]: glxtest: libGL.so.1 missing
Crash Annotation GraphicsCriticalError: |[0][GFX1-]: glxtest: libpci missing (t=0.323898) |[1][GFX1-]: glxtest: libGL.so.1 missing (t=0.32393) |[2][GFX1-]: glxtest: libEGL missing (t=0.323941) [GFX1-]: glxtest: libEGL missing
Crash Annotation GraphicsCriticalError: |[0][GFX1-]: glxtest: libpci missing (t=0.323898) |[1][GFX1-]: glxtest: libGL.so.1 missing (t=0.32393) |[2][GFX1-]: glxtest: libEGL missing (t=0.323941) |[3][GFX1-]: No GPUs detected via PCI (t=0.323959) [GFX1-]: No GPUs detected via PCI
```

But sadly nothing worked.
Can I have a fix or better way for doing it?

Edit:
Chromium version - 93.0.4577.82,
Firefox version - 94.0,
Puppeteer version - 10.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the last line in those docs?

```
# Run everything after as non-privileged user.
USER pptruser
```

Comment: Ofcrs yes. I tried everything out there.